# Proper use of hook_menu_breadcrumb_alter()

Tags: routes, breadcrumbs

I have a situation where I need to mess with a breadcrumb on a page and insert some items in the middle.  In my instance [`drupal_set_breadcrumb()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_set_breadcrumb/7) can't be used, so I need to implement a [`hook_menu_breadcrumb_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_breadcrumb_alter/7).  I am a little confused about proper usage with this, though, and am not terribly familiar with the guts of how the menu module works.

Is there a proper method for building elements that go into the `$active_trail` array, eg

```
$foo = array(
  'title' => $node->title,
  'href' => 'node/' . $node->nid,
  'link_path' => '',
  'localized_options' => array(),
  'type' => 0,
);
```

`title` and `href` are easy enough, but I don't quite get how the other play into this particular context.  It is easy enough to figure this out from what is there, but I would like to do "the right thing".

Is there a proper method (or best practice) for testing whether `$item` is a node and to load it?  Again, I can `dpm($item)`, poke around, and get what I need.

I have what I need working, but it is messy and would like to fix it for the long term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties for each trail item that are documented are the following:

- title: Title of the item
- href: Drupal path of the item
- localized_options: Options for passing into the `l()` function
- type: A menu type constant, such as `MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK`, or 0 to indicate it's not really in the menu (used for the home page item)

The code that builds the breadcrumbs is the following.

```
foreach ($active_trail as $parent) {
  $breadcrumb[] = l($parent['title'], $parent['href'], $parent['localized_options']);
}
```

The other values (type and link_path) are not used to create the breadcrumbs, but they could be used from other modules that alter the breadcrumbs. Using the default values used from `menu_set_active_trail()` for those properties probably causes less compatibility problems with other modules.

```
$trail[] = array(
  'title' => t('Home'), 
  'href' => '<front>', 
  'link_path' => '', 
  'localized_options' => array(), 
  'type' => 0,
);
```

> Is there a proper method (or best practice) for testing whether `$item` is a node and to load it?

The `$item` argument `hook_menu_breadcrumb_alter()` gets is the value returned from [menu_get_item()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_item/7). If you want to check it is for a node, you can use the following code.

```
if (isset($item['load_functions'][2]) && !empty($item['map'][3]) && $item['load_functions'][4] == 'node_load') {
  $node = $router_item['map'][5];
}
else {
  // The menu item is not for a node.
}
```

That is the code executed from [menu_get_object()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) when it is called with its default arguments.

#### References

- [menu_get_active_breadcrumb()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_active_breadcrumb/7)
- [menu_set_active_trail()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_set_active_trail/7)

Comment: Thanks, didn't think to check menu_get_object().  I clarified the portion about the $active_trail.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: You know, I don't know how many times I read that API page and never put two-and-two together about the bottom section.  Thanks.

Comment: Writing this answer helped me with [finding a bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154936/adding-a-new-link-to-a-post-messes-up-the-code-already-present-in-the-post). I was going crazy rewriting the code all times I added a new link, as `$item['map'][1]` was interpreted as Markdown link, and rewritten. At the end, I had to manually add Markdown links. `:)`