# Active menu for a node with two different terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, routes

I have a node which has two different terms. The problem is when I'm on such a node, the active menu and breadcrumbs point only to one of the terms. How can I find a solution to this problem without duplicate that node for each term. Or if you have an idea how to duplicate that node but they will be edited in one place that's is also a good solution.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the breadcrumb using [`hook_menu_breadcrumb_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_breadcrumb_alter/7) in your custom module. There's an answer about proper using of `hook_menu_breadcrumb_alter()` similar to your use case and with helpful references at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/49952/10176